# how to create hyperlink to got to next component from one component in react like a tag does?

Tags: react-native, react-fullstack, reactjs

****(The main issue Link should work, but it should be encapsulate inside the router. If encapsulated than obviously , it would like nested router. which i dont want. i just want to render register component only when i click the link below)****

return (

```
            <h1>Login Page</h1>

         Its the login form, no issue with login form
            <form action="">

                <button }>Login</button>

            </form>

           <

           **(The main issue is this should work, but it should be encapsulate inside the router. If encapsulated than obviously , it would like nested router. which i dont want. i just want to render register component only when i click the link below)**


          <Link to="" component={Register}> Create Account </Link>


        </div>
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and use Link to declare the path, then use Route inside a switch to give functionality.

```
 <h1>Login Page</h1>

   Its the login form, no issue with login form
            <form action="">
                <button>Login</button>
            </form>


   <Link to="path/here" component={Register}> Create Account </Link>

   <Switch>
   <Route path="path/here">
   < Register />
   </Route>
   </Switch>
```

Of course you will have to import Route and Switch